# CanvasJs in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, canvasjs

I am trying to use canvasJS in my typescript file. I have the declaration file - index.d.ts. and the corresponding javascript file is https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js. 
I am using require.js in my  project. Unfortunately when I run, webpage crashes indicating that require.js couldn't find the corresponding index.js. 
If i create an index.js and copy contents of the https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js. everything will be fine.

I don't want to do that. Instead I would like the index.d.ts to directly refer or look for the url. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `index.d.ts` only holds the definition, it will not import any library. What I would suggest is to use `npm install canvasjs` to install the package, then add the types using: `npm install --save @types/canvasjs`. This will put the canvasjs into the `node_modules`.
When you try importing it using

```
import CanvasJS from 'canvasjs';
```

typescript will try resolving the import the library using [those rules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), in short, it will recursively try finding the `node_modules` folder starting from the file importing the canvasjs and escalating the task to its parent folder if not found.

Another way is to put the import `https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js` in the header of your html file (assuming you do have one) or somewhere in your js code, add the typing to npm using `npm install --save @types/canvasjs` and finally modify the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["canvasjs"]
   }
}
```